# Can any D&D god grant a Cleric spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, religions-and-deities

In D&D 3.5e and the official expanded books, it seems Greyhawk has about 10,000 different gods; some just mentioned in a table somewhere.

There's nothing that I can find in the rulebooks, but I read here [in a wiki](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Divine_Ranks) that some "gods" cannot grant spells, such as **Rank 0** and **Overdeities**. However, I've seen nothing in any rule-books that define which "Rank" any god is.

So I'm unsure if this was just made up by a wiki author, or maybe I'm missing something.

In particular, there are monster deities, such as Maglubiyet, which from what I can tell was only briefly mentioned in errata for MM1, that I can't really tell where they sit in the default Pantheon.

Comment: Despite dandwiki containing a lot of homebrew content, that page is part of the actual D&D 3.5e d20 SRD. It's not just wiki content, it's not user-edited, it is (or should be) an exact reproduction of the official d20 SRD. That text is also found on the [corresponding *d20srd.org* page](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineRanksAndPowers.htm). *d20srd.org* contains no homebrew and is reliably *only* a reproduction of the d20 SRD text.

Comment: @doppelgreener (Because its ads don't crash my browser, I usually prefer [this reproduction of the SRD](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/home.html), which is similarly faithful yet not as extensively hyperlinked and slightly harder to search.)

Comment: @doppelgreener Strictly speaking, d20srd.org does contain one (1) marked piece of homebrew: the scorpionfolk monster listed in the Monsters section.

Comment: @KRyan - nice catch!

Comment: Afaik overdeities could grant spells, but they do not. They are too far above us.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A deity with [divine rank](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineRanksAndPowers.htm) 0 can't grant spells, and a deity with [divine rank](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineRanksAndPowers.htm) 21 or higher does not grant spells. [*Deities and Demigods*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786926546) (Apr. 2002) covers divinity in much greater detail.

According to the *Official Listing of Deities for Use in the Campaign* (version 2.0) (Mar. 2002) for the now-defunct [Living Greyhawk](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=lg/welcome) campaign, [Maglubiyet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goblinoid_deities#Maglubiyet) is a greater deity therefore possessing divine rank 16-20, making the High Chieftain perfectly capable of granting his goblinoid worshipers spells.